# Place div on top of everything

Tags: css, drupal, css-float

I have a Drupal website loaded with AJAX. Every time I edit my title, AJAX is checking whether or not I've actually changed it. But every time the AJAX starts checking, my whole lay-out is jumping around...

**BEFORE**
[image]

**AFTER**
[image]

I tried to edit the `.ajax-threbber`-css class with position `absolute`, `relative` and `fixed`, but no result. Every time the throbber reacts differently. A `z-index` of 99999999999 doesn't work either... Is there a way to float this `ajax-throbber`-div to the absolute top without influencing any other items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would first need to check its current CSS properties, it could be that you are having them overwritten by something else.

Firebug or Google Chrome developer tools would help.  Setting the position to absolute, should do it for you, its just CSS gets murky if you don't consider other pieces of the puzzle acting upon your object that you are trying to style.

Comment: But it's AJAX, so the div disappears as fast as it appears... It's only there for less then 2 seconds. How can I check the CSS properties

Comment: If youa re using firbug, add a breakpoint in the js code where the box pops up.  This will stop the execution and allow you to inspect the css, js variables. http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html

Comment: ajax = javascript, you can create a breakpoint, or at least right click the element in chrome and 'inspect' before it goes away. Either way it is a styling issue you need to first understand to fix, you are trying to fix something you don't yet understand thats why the CSS won't work.